# Prove that a set of formulas is consistent

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let $\Sigma$ be a set of formulas. Show that if for any formula $\phi\in\Sigma$ that $\Sigma-{\phi}$ does not imply $\neg\phi$ than $\Sigma$ is a consistent set.

I'm having problem showing that the set is consistent, I'm trying to show by contradiction that if there is a formula $\phi$ that both it and it's negeation is implied by the set than it breaks the assumption but I can only show that this is the case if $\phi\in\Sigma$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need $\Sigma \vdash \phi \land \lnot \phi$ for **one** formula $\phi$ to show that $\Sigma$ is inconsistent. Here's how I would answer the problem:

Assume $\Sigma$ is inconsistent. Then $\Sigma$ is certainly not empty. So let $\phi \in \Sigma$ and let $\bot$ be any false formula, e.g., $\phi \land \lnot \phi$, so that $\lnot \phi$ is logically equivalent to $\phi \Rightarrow \bot$. Since $\Sigma$ is inconsistent, $\Sigma \vdash \bot$. By the deduction theorem, $\Sigma - \phi \vdash \phi \Rightarrow \bot$ and hence $\Sigma - \phi \vdash \lnot \phi$.